# Javascript not properly iterating over array?

Tags: javascript, arrays, for-loop

So I'm making a little roguelike game in Javascript and have an error with a piece of my rendering code. Not the rendering itself but a little sub-part of it that iterates over an array of objects, checking if any of the objects have coordinates that match the x and y parameters, then returning the object if coordinates match.

Here's the code giving me trouble

```
Client.Render.checkObjects = function(objects, x, y) {
    for (var a = 0; a < objects.length; a++) {
        if (objects[a].x == x && objects[a].y == y) {
            return objects[a];
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }
};
```

I have an array of objects called testSnap.objects which I made like this:

```
function testObject(x, y) {
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
    this.symbol = "a";
};
testSnap.objects.push(new testObject(5,5));
testSnap.objects.push(new testObject(3,5));
```

I then try

```
console.log(Client.Render.checkObjects(testSnap.objects, 5, 5));
console.log(Client.Render.checkObjects(testSnap.objects, 3, 5));
```

Which returns:

```
Object { x: 5, y: 5, symbol: "a" }
false
```

It seems `objects[a]` is never `objects[1]`?

Comment: `checkObjects` returns `false` on the first iteration, before it ever gets to `objects[1]`

Comment: Yep, that's the issue. return will cancel your iteration. Well explained question TBF

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You'll only ever return an object if the *first* object matches. If it doesn't, you're immediately returning false.  Try:

```
Client.Render.checkObjects = function(objects, x, y) {
  for (var a = 0; a < objects.length; a++) {
    if (objects[a].x == x && objects[a].y == y) {
        return objects[a];
    }
  }

  // NOW return false if we never matched
  return false;
};
```

Answer (score 4):

Your `return false` statement needs to be after your `for` loop; otherwise `false` will be returned when the first object does not match.